# How remove tags just have one post?

Tags: tags

I have a auto feed [website](https://akhbarejadid.com/)  and there are too many unsueful tags that have just one or two post. Is there any sql code to clear all of these tags from database at once?!

Answer (score 0):

I found the sql code and It works fine. I just change 0 to 1

```
DELETE FROM wp_terms WHERE term_id IN (SELECT term_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE count = 0 );
```